# Unable to use Stack Overflow chat despite having enough reputation

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, chat

I have 24 reputation points, but SO chat is still giving me the message "you must have 20 reputation...." Why can't I join the chat?

Answer (score 7):

Your reputation is synced to the chat site hourly, so Chat.SO currently thinks you only have 19 reputation. You can force a refresh by logging out of chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/logout) and then logging back in.