# I have enough reputation but can't get to the chat room?

Tags: support

I have 21 reputation here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2835880/tim-timmy

But it won't let me get into chat (I only have 19): https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2835880/tim-timmy

Why is this so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You got the 2 reputation points for the edit only 5 minutes ago. Since the reputation system is cached, it may take longer for Chat to see you're above 20 reputation. I [think](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84683/220538) the reputation on Chat is updated hourly but I'm not quite sure though. You can either wait for an hour for the reputation to update, or simply force a refresh by [logging out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/logout) of the chat and then back in.

See also: [10 rep missing intermittently from account overview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121741/220538)

Comment: I'll see and if it does work, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It has been 6 minutes already and it is still not working!

Comment: Give it some time. Patience your grasshopper. That will indeed be the issue.

Comment: Okay dokey Bart, I'll be patient.

Comment: @TimTimmy: See the updated answer.

Comment: @AmalMurali: I know this is stupid, but where in the world is the log out button?!

Comment: @TimTimmy: There isn't a button (AFAIK). Simply click on the link in my answer.

Comment: @TimTimmy: Looks like it's been [updated](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jG0Yg.png). You should now be able to enter any chat rooms. ;)